# R: Struggling to use regular expression to alter objects within a vector

Tags: r, regex

I have taken the top results from a larger database to make this simple and placed them in the vector below:

```
trialsid <- c(t16740429-1, t16740429-2, t16740429-3, t16740429-4, t16740429-5)
```

Now if we focus on t16740429-1, the aim would be to transform it into 1674-04-29, however I am unsure how to achieve this.

I think that I would need to do something like this:

```
trialid_readable <- trialid %>% paste0(str_replace(?), "-", str_replace(?), "-", str_replace(?))
```

Creating capture groups to achieve.

I have also thought about the regular expressions = \\d{1,4}, \\d{5,6} and \\d{7,8}.

Yet I am unsure how to bring it all together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using base R:

```
trialsid <- c('t16740429-1', 't16740429-2', 't16740429-3', 't16740429-4', 't16740429-5')
trialsid
[1] "t16740429-1" "t16740429-2" "t16740429-3" "t16740429-4" "t16740429-5"
gsub('t(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})-.','\\1-\\2-\\3',trialsid)
[1] "1674-04-29" "1674-04-29" "1674-04-29" "1674-04-29" "1674-04-29"
```

Answer (score 0):

`{n,m}` means match between `n` and `m` occurrences of the previous pattern:

```r
str_replace(trialsid, "t(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2}).+", "\\1-\\2-\\3")
[1] "1674-04-29" "1674-04-29" "1674-04-29" "1674-04-29" "1674-04-29"
```